# Exp:resso Store - skipping payment gateways, free orders

Tags: expresso-store

slightly strange requirement! We have a setup which requires the user to reserve the products they want to buy via an add to cart/checkout system.

So they add what they want to basket, click 'reserve' (checkout, if you like), fill out their name, the date they want to collect it and the store that want to collect it from, then submit it so the site admin can sort it out for collection. No payment involved (though that might come later).

Is this something Exp:resso Store can handle? Effectively skipping the payment bit and submitting a free order, despite the products having prices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be best suited to use the Manual Payment Gateway ([doc link](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/payment_gateways.html#manual)). It is intended for things like bank transfers or cheque but would also serve the purpose of allowing the order to be completed without requiring a user to enter any payment details.

You could then use the `{exp:store:payments}` tag pair down the road to allow for the user to make a payment.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'll give it a whirl in that case!

Comment: For future people searching, now if the total is 0 order is automatically confirmed even if you have just one payment gateway, no need for "manual" as Justing mentioned.